# Calculating upper eccentricity in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I was going through a paper. There calculating *upper eccentricity* was mentioned.
Can anybody help me in finding out how it was done? I tried hard but was unable to get it.
A little hint or explanation of only one vertex is welcome. That would help me a lot. Thanks a lot.

- [Centers of $n$-Fold Tensor Products of Graphs](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/reprints/DMGT04.pdf), page $495$, Fig. $1$

Comment: Please link us to the actual paper. (Google results change depending on who is searching and where they're searching from!)

Comment: here is the link www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/reprints/DMGT04.pdf‎

Comment: not able to copy link here.... papers is "
Centers of n-Fold Tensor Products of Graphs"

Comment: Oh... I didnt notice the edits ... Thanks @anon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure in the paper is the following:

[image: The figure in the paper]

The vertices are marked by an ordered pair.  In the first coordinate is the usual eccentricity of the vertex, namely $\mathrm{ecc}(v)=\max_u \mathrm{dist}(u,v)$, where $\mathrm{dist}(u,v)$ is the number of steps in the shortest walk from $u$ to $v$.

The second coordinate contains the upper eccentricity, which is defined similarly, except we ignore walks that have the same parity as $\mathrm{ecc}(v)$ (meaning walks of length congruent to $\mathrm{ecc}(v) \pmod 2$).

So, for example, the upper eccentricity of $b$ above is $4$ since we cannot get to $a$ in $0$ or $2$ steps, but can reach $a$ in $4$ steps (we're not allowed to use an odd number of steps since $\mathrm{ecc}(b) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$).  We can also reach either $c$ or $d$ in $2$ steps.

The upper eccentricity of $a$ is $5$, since we cannot get from $a$ to $a$ in $1$ or $3$ steps, but can reach $a$ in $5$ steps.

Comment: Wow .... wonderful explanation....now its very much clear to me. thanks a lot....